# Ethereum Transactions Take So long

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions, hash-algorithm

It's first time when I tried to make an Ethereum wallet and to make a transfer. 
Compared to what I am used with other type of d.currency, this transaction seems to be taking forever.

In almost 24h windows not even 10% of the blocks have been approved. [transcation link](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9bd221b2bc305afe020ba9712478d4d3b3f03dba0d683a5f5e9dfe2a6a2cd921).

Is there a way to speed up the process or to know an estimate when it will be finished or to just cancel it and return the funds?

Details:

Feed Paid: 0.000441 Ether
Gas Used: 21,000
Gas Price: 0.000000021 Ether (21 Gwei)
Transaction ID: 0x9bd221b2bc305afe020ba9712478d4d3b3f03dba0d683a5f5e9dfe2a6a2cd921
4371658 (7837 block confirmations)

Using MyEtherWallet

Thanks

Comment: Yesterday was the switch from to a new version of the Ethereum protocol and everything should work better if you use the new version. If you are still in the old chain your transaction will take much longer to process because you are in the wrong chain!

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how do I change the chain?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version

Comment: I did some research and MyEtherWallet updates automatically, so no need for that. I managed to see a confirmation that the transaction went through so I am just waiting for a confirmation from the receiver. Thanks for your advice

Comment: i am trying to send coins from MEW to IDEX wallet and its been 4 hours. I am currently sitting at over 1000 confirmations... just wondering why its taking to long. just wondering if i can cancel this and figure out a new way so the coins get into the wallet quicker? thanks https://etherscan.io/tx/0xde4269e9d46d44371464600162fcb9dbcf7d6f15bd622bfd786da6b9edfa1710

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 4371658 (7837 block confirmations)

This means that your transaction was mined in block 4371658. That block was at [Oct-16-2017 03:00:36 PM +UTC](https://etherscan.io/block/4371658), about 21 hours *before* your question was posted.

The 7837 block confirmations means that the transaction is irrevocably part of the network. Usually 30 or so confirmations are regarded as enough, which is 7-8 minutes after the transaction is mined.

> In almost 24h windows not even 10% of the blocks have been approved.

I don't know what this means, but it seems to be based on a misunderstanding of how things work.

Basically, as soon as you have around 30 block confirmations, your transaction is complete.